# How to read IMediaSample 24 bit PCM data

Tags: c#, audio, directshow, pcm, audio-processing

I have the following method which collects PCM data from the IMediaSample into floats for the FFT:

```
    public int PCMDataCB(IntPtr Buffer, int Length, ref TDSStream Stream, out float[] singleChannel)
    {
        int numSamples = Length / (Stream.Bits / 8);
        int samplesPerChannel = numSamples / Stream.Channels;

        float[] samples = new float[numSamples];

        if (Stream.Bits == 32 && Stream.Float) {
            // this seems to work for 32 bit floating point
            byte[] buffer32f = new byte[numSamples * 4];
            Marshal.Copy(Buffer, buffer32f, 0, numSamples);

            for (int j = 0; j < buffer32f.Length; j+=4)
            {
                samples[j / 4] = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] { buffer32f[j + 0], buffer32f[j + 1], buffer32f[j + 2], buffer32f[j + 3]}, 0);
            }
        }
        else if (Stream.Bits == 24)
        {
            // I need this code
        }

        // compress result into one mono channel
        float[] result = new float[samplesPerChannel];

        for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i += Stream.Channels)
        {
            float tmp = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < Stream.Channels; j++)
                tmp += samples[i + j] / Stream.Channels;

            result[i / Stream.Channels] = tmp;
        }

        // mono output to be used for visualizations
        singleChannel = result;

        return 0;
    }
```

Seems to work for 32b float, because I get sensible data in the spectrum analyzer (although it seems too shifted(or compressed?) to the lower frequencies).

I also seem to manage to make it work for 8, 16 and 32 non float, but I can only read garbage when the bits are 24.

How can I adapt this to work with 24 bit PCM coming into Buffer?

Buffer comes from an IMediaSample.

Another thing I am wondering is if the method I use to add all channels to one by summing and dividing by the number of channels is ok...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
byte[] buffer24 = new byte[numSamples * 3];
Marshal.Copy(Buffer, buffer24, 0, numSamples * 3);
var window = (float)(255 << 16 | 255 << 8 | 255);

for (int j = 0; j < buffer24.Length; j+=3)
{
    samples[j / 3] = (buffer24[j] << 16 | buffer24[j + 1] << 8 | buffer24[j + 2]) / window;
}
```

Creates a integer from the three bytes and then scales it into the range 1/-1 by dividing with the max value of three bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
byte[] buffer24f = new byte[numSamples * 3];
Marshal.Copy(Buffer, buffer24f, 0, numSamples);

for (int j = 0; j < buffer24f.Length; j+=3)
{
    samples[j / 3] = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(
            new byte[] { 
                0, 
                buffer24f[j + 0], 
                buffer24f[j + 1], 
                buffer24f[j + 2]
            }, 0);
}
```

Comment: 24 bits is not floating point. It is integer audio. If something needs to be done is figure out how to compose an integer from the byte buffer and then cast it to float to put into the samples array.